# How can I label a certain mob, and pull it later

Tags: python

I send this code through a program to decide which mobs the user will be fighting, but every time it gets to this it produces  "Headless_Horseman (or whichever mob it picks) is undefined." I  cannot figure out how to 'define' the name.

```
def mob_picker_randmob1 ():
    global Zombie
    global Zambie
    global Giant_Worm
    global Headless_Horseman
    global Skeleton
    global Ghost
    global Ghoul
    global Baby_Sister
    global Little_Sister
    global Big_Sister
    randmob1=random.randint(1,5)
    if randmob1 == 1:
        randmob1 = Zombie
        mob_picker_randmob2 ()
    elif randmob1 == 2:
        randmob1 = Skeleton
        mob_picker_randmob2 ()
    elif randmob1 == 3:
        randmob1 = Giant_Worm
        mob_picker_randmob2 ()
    elif randmob1 == 4:
        randmob1 = Headless_Horseman
        mob_picker_randmob2 ()
    elif randmob1 == 5:
        randmob1 = Zambie
        mob_picker_randmob2 ()
```

Comment: Where are you defining the `Headless_Horseman` variable initially?

Comment: Did you mean to use strings?

Comment: All your ifs besides the last should probably be elifs instead.

Comment: `mob_picker_randmob2` should be called after the ifs, since it appears in every branch regardless of our choice.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. This is not valid Python as it stands.

Comment: You also need to add the code for the `mob_picker_randmob2()` function. Note also that all those `global` statements aren't needed since you don't assign new values to any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to assign values to the variables in your main function, since you are declaring these as global variables.

```
Zombie = 'zombie'
Zambie = 'zAmbie'
Giant_Worm = 'big worm'
Headless_Horseman = 'horseman without head'
```

Also, consider using random.choice()

```
choices = (
    Zombie, Zambie, Giant_Worm, Headless_Horseman, Skeleton,
    Ghost, Ghoul, Baby_Sister, Little_Sister, Big_Sister,
)
return random.choice(choices)
```

Comment: If you declare them all with the value 1, the function will always pick the value 1.

Comment: Assigning them all to 1 has nothing to do with which one gets picked. Granted, if they are all assigned 1 then the function would always return 1, but without knowing what the OP wants these set to, assigning them to 1 fixes the "undefined" error.  The OP can assign them to whatever he wants, but he must assign them to something.